# Is there a SVN plugin for SQL Server Management Studio 2005 or 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, svn, sql-server-2008, tortoisesvn

Looking for a "Source Control" plugin to integrate SSMS with Subversion/SVN.  Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 7):

Redgate's solution seems to be for versioning your database, not your files in your Solution Explorer. I've found two options for solution versioning:

1) Setting up TortoiseSVN as an external tool: http://jrummell.com/sql-server-management-studio-and-tortoisesvn

2) Agent SVN: http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/ssms/ms_ssms.html

I've tried neither of these options yet, but perhaps this helps someone's search

Comment: As you correctly point out, Agent SVN works with SSMS, but since it also supports the MS-SCCI, it will work with other MS-SCCI compliant IDEs including the Visual Studio family of IDEs.

Comment: Updated [jrummell link](http://jrummell.azurewebsites.net/sql-server-management-studio-and-tortoisesvn/)

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I know of at the moment is an Early Access Program for [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm) from RedGate.

**It is an EAP though, so is not even a complete but rough-around-the-edges product yet.**

Comment: We've shipped SQL Source Control 1.0 now. Please try it out and let us know if it meets your requirements. http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete solution from Redgate. Here is the URL: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, but have you tried database projects in Visual Studio?  That's what I would recommend for developing and storing SQL scripts.  And in VS you can use Ankh or VisualSVN.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked pretty good for me in the past.  Haven't tried with 2008, but I am guessing that it would work too.

[Codeproject ScriptDB4Svn](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ScriptDB4Svn.aspx)

Comment: I do not dare try it today. Last developer activity was back in 2006. Too much can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before and been pretty happy with it.

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/)

Comment: This is for Visual Studio, not for SQL Server Management Studio.